# What permissions do I add in AWS to enable ecr:getAuthorizationToken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to [follow the steps](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/authenticating-amazon-ecr-repositories-for-docker-cli-with-credential-helper/) to use amazon elastic container registry (ECR) but I'm stuck at the first step, which is obtaining an auth token.

Command:

```
aws ecr get-login
```

Or...

```
aws ecr get-login --region=us-west-2
```

Error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::9#####4:user/### is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
```

AWS Permissions on user for region us-west-2:

```
AmazonEC2FullAccess
AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess
Billing
AdministratorAccess
AmazonECS_FullAccess
```

AWS CLI version:

```
aws help --version
aws-cli/1.14.40 Python/3.6.4 Darwin/18.2.0 botocore/1.8.44
```

Comment: Have you looked in the actual error documentations? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/common-errors.html

Answer (score 4):

Please note that you're not allowing your user any access to ECR in a sense. 
Try adding the following policy to the user:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:ListImages",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}]
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html#AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly

Answer (score 4):

As general advice, `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` must apparently be applied to all resources `*` but all other ECR permissions can be scoped. When setting up ECR permissions as below, that user/role can login into Docker via CLI and still only access those images that user/role is supposed to.

Example with scoped permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {           
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:${region}:${account}:repository/${repo-name}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

From my observations, scoping `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` to any ECR repositories will result in `AccessDeniedException`.